# How does one resize an image thats larger that the div container to fit perfectly in it(auto resize, zoom out etc...)

Tags: html, css, shopify

This is the code i have and im using it on a shopify store.

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:404px;">
  <img style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain; background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2233/7153/files/Grade_photo_shoot__0056.jpg?13831580932505769974);' />
</div>
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

and this is the original image:

[image]

Comment: use `background-size: cover;`

Comment: KKinda got it somewhere it fits on desktop but mobile is extremely squashed i used background-size:100% 100%;

Comment: So you  want the image to stay at full view in desktop and mobile ?

Comment: Yes full view, so kwwp its apec ratio when scaling down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code:

```css
#myCanvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.image {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2233/7153/files/Grade_photo_shoot__0056.jpg?13831580932505769974');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:404px;">
  <div class="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome an perfect that helped a lot